# Azure Mobile Service To App Service Confusion

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services

I have been developing an Azure Mobile Service, and I've Implemented code-first migrations as the data model changed a lot during development, and I didn't want to lose my data, as the default behaviour In Azure Mobile Services is to drop the backing SQL database table whenever the data model changes.

This mobile service is not yet in production, but I'd like to migrate it over to the new Azure App Service (Mobile App), and I have completed all the necessary tweaks to get my TableControllers etc working as I like them.

Obviously on first deployment to App Service I don't need to worry about Data Model changes, but at some point I am going to change something.
Whilst there is plenty of posts about doing code first migrations for the old Azure Mobile Service, there seems to be nothing for the new service.

More surprisingly, in the Azure portal the new App Service doesn't seem to be backed by SQL server as there seems to be no SQL server instance assigned to this service.

So my questions are:

1) Is the new Azure App Service backed by SQL server ? and if so why cant I get connection details in Azure portal ?

2) If it is backed by SQL server, how to we make model changes without losing data.

I have searched and searched on the interwebs for this, but there seems no straight-forward answers (just a general lack of information)

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes.  Look in Application Settings under Connection Strings

2) If you are doing Node, then ALTER TABLE is done - not a drop/create.  If you are doing ASP.NET, then that is backed by Entity Framework, so the standard EF rules apply - do EF Migrations.  You can also turn off the framework managing your tables using this in your `App_Start/AzureMobile.cs` (or whatever filename contains the startup logic)

```
    // Initialize the database with EF Code First
    // Database.SetInitializer(new AzureMobileInitializer());
    Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);
```

The commented out line is my original initializer.  The un-commented version is the new one that doesn't do any changes to the database.  If you do this, you are responsible for the SQL changes to update the database for the model.

I'm currently doing a "30 days of ZUMO" blog series at https://shellmonger.com - I'm currently covering Node, but I'll get to ASP.NET eventually (probably early May)

Comment: There are no connection strings in application settings, which is why I'm confused. The app service definitely gives me my data back, so its storing it somewhere

Comment: In that case, you must have them in your web.config. To see the values, go to your Kudu site. Go to Tools -> Kudu in the Azure portal, or go to your-site.scm.azurewebsites.net. There, you can see all environment variables. Look for MS_TableConnectionString.

Comment: MS_TableConnectionString isnt included in the environment variables on the Kudu page

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have finally gotten to the bottom of this, with the help of Adrian Hall's answer.

The issue is a combination of poor documentation, inadequate 'new project' wizard in Visual Studio, and my assumption that everything should work as expected.

Firstly, I created the App Service mobile app in Visual Studio, rather than via the azure portal. I then successfully deployed it from Visual Studio, unaware that more setup needs to be done online.

Essentially, an app service when created is without a database by default (which in hindsight is probably why I wasn't asked for database details in the Visual Studio new project wizard).

You have to manually configure a new database connection in azure portal, where you can also create a new SQL database as required.

This issue was compounded by my own incompetence - I had configured my client code to use offline sync, so whenever I started up my client app I saw the previous data - leading me to the assumption that the server project must have some data storage. In truth my local PushAsync wasn't actually doing anything.

Now that I have a properly configured data connection, everything seems to be in-line with Adrian Halls answer - which was correct.